# Android: show/hide the android soft keyboard

Tags: android

How can I disable and enable the virtual keyboard when the user click on the EditText.
If I use the instruction `EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` the cursor does not blink and when I set it not focusable the cursor disappear.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread?
[hide/display soft input]


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Force open soft keyboard

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Force close soft keyboard

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(_pay_box_helper.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(your_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.showSoftInputFromWindow(your_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```